# how to change language cookie without change url using controller in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, controller

i want change language cookie . i create LanguageController that change language cookie but when i want use this controller , my url is changed but i dont want change url and just change cookie with select language

```
      public ActionResult Change(String lang)
        {
        if (lang != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
        }

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookie.Value = lang;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to your home/index page. You can redirect to the calling page using something like

```
return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```